# Input validation without using try catch exception

Tags: java, validation, input

Im writing a program that calculates the investment of a person after a number of years. I prompt the users to enter their name, amount they will be investing, interest rate, and number of years. I'm supposed to do a validation of the input with if...else statements. One of the checks is to see if the user has entered the correct data type. This is for an intro java class. We finished the chapter on methods a week ago, so this is beginner's stuff. I can seem to figure out how to do the data type check.  I tried the hasNextInt for my int types but I get an exception which we haven't learned at all. I found some info online on the Pattern and Match classes but there's a lot of stuff in there that we haven't seen yet. Here's one of the methods I wrote to get the correct input.

```
  //Define method for input validation, integer type
  public static int getValidInt(String messagePrompt, String messagePrompt2, String messagePrompt3){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//Create scanner
  int returnValue;
  int j = 0;
    do {//Start validation loop
        System.out.printf(messagePrompt); //Print input request        
        returnValue = input.nextInt();

    if (returnValue <= 0) { //Check if user entered a positive number 
        System.out.println(messagePrompt2);//Print error message
      }
    else if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(messagePrompt3);//Print error message

        }          
      else {
          j++;
          }
    } while (j == 0);//End validation loop

  return returnValue;
```

}

Im not sure if I have the order of the checks right. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the error that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

If it's just 4 pre-defined input fields and you don't have to check for additional things then I don't see a reason to use a do while loop here. Though maybe I don't get what this method is supposed to do, are you returning some kind of integer that defines whether the input was valid or do you actually have to store the values? If the former, why not just return a Boolean or an Enumeration?

I also don't understand why you're simply calling nextInt the first time, but for the next one you are checking whether it has a nextInt.

Also you don't mention what kind of exception you're getting when calling hasNextInt, but apparently this can only be an `IllegalStateException`. I suggest taking a look at the Java docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, or reading your relevant course material.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()` is invoked. First one is used to read the value from input, and second is used to see whether the value type is int. So you have to invoke `hasNext[Type]()` followed by `next[Type]`.

Let's correct those two first as below.

```
if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
    int userChoice =  scnr.nextInt();
} else {
    // input is not an int
}
```

Now let's correct your code to get a valid int.

```
public static int getValidInt(String messagePrompt, String messagePrompt2, String messagePrompt3) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// Create scanner
    int returnValue = -1;
    boolean incorrectInput = true;

    while (incorrectInput) {

        System.out.printf(messagePrompt); // Print input request

        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            returnValue = input.nextInt();

            if (returnValue <= 0) { // Check if user entered a positive number
                System.out.println(messagePrompt2);// Print error message
            } else {
                incorrectInput = false;
            }
        } else {
            input.next();
            System.out.println(messagePrompt3);// Print error message
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```